# Trocar src de imagem com variável PHP / HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, image

se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria grato. Eu gostaria de criar uma estrutura onde o caminho do arquivo fosse trocado por um botão que altera o numero da imagem, dessa forma:

Varíavel XXX = número da imagem (image_XXXX.jpg)

Primeiro penso que teria de atribuir 0001 ao numero da imagem, isso seria no carregamento da página, certo?

XXXX = 0001;

---

**BOTÃO PRÓXIMA IMAGEM**

---

**Se** XXXX = 1303
       Não fazer nada, afinal esta é a última imagem
**Senão**
       Adiciona 1 ao numero da imagem
       Mostrar imagem

---

**BOTÃO PRÓXIMA ANTERIOR**

---

**Se** XXXX = 1
       Não fazer nada, afinal esta é a primeira imagem
**Senão**
       Remove 1 ao numero da imagem
       Mostrar imagem

Se alguém souber como fazer usando PHP / JAVASCRIPT / HTML eu agradeço.

Comment: Se postar o código envolvido na pergunta, terás mais chances que alguém te responda. Leia esse post que vai te ajudar a elaborar melhor suas perguntas. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stackoverflow não distribui código, apenas revisa ou corrigi

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira que você pensou, mas precisaria usar php e javascript para fazer requisições assíncronas.

Uma maneira mais simples que vejo de fazer isso é usando somente javascript mesmo.
Inicialmente você precisa de algo como:

```
<img src="/caminho/para/imagem-1.jpg" />
```

E partir disso tem várias maneiras de mudar o número final.
Uma seria pegar o valor do atributo `src` e fazer split para tirar o valor, por exemplo.
Porém também daria muito trabalho. Se fosse eu fazendo eu usaria um *data attribute* para controlar esse número.
Então apenas uma pequena mudança na sua imagem e fica assim:

```
<img data-count="1" src="/caminho/para/imagem-1.jpg" />
```

Com isso agora é possível fazer esse controle de trocar a imagem somente com o javascript de forma rápida, fácil e também eficiente, já que você só vai trocar o `src` e com isso o próprio browser se encarrega de recarregar a imagem.

De forma geral ficaria assim:

```
<img data-count="1" src="/caminho/para/imagem-1.jpg" />

<script>
  $('#botaoProximo').onclick(function(){
    var proxima = parseInt( $("img").attr("data-count") ) + 1;
    $("img").attr("src", "/caminho/para/imagem-"+ proxima +".jpg");
  });

  $('#botaoVoltar').onclick(function(){
    var anterior = parseInt( $("img").attr("data-count") ) - 1;
    $("img").attr("src", "/caminho/para/imagem-"+ anterior +".jpg");
  });
</script>
```

Claro que ainda tem que fazer os botões e também poderia colocar um `id` na tag da imagem para usar no seletor do jQuery para não bugar tudo caso você adicione outra e por aí em diante, mas creio que deu para entender o conceito.

Espero ter ajudado.
Um grande abraço!

## Editado

Lembre-se também de atualizar o valor de `data-count` a cada clique em cada um dos botões.
Eu esqueci de colocar isso no código, mas é importante para que funcione corretamente...